# Error attaching or detaching virtual disk

Tags: windows-server-2019, storage-spaces

I just physically moved my home lab from one house to another and my storage space for my primary array will not re-attach.  The message I get is "Error attaching or detaching virtual disk: Failed to attach virtual disk to MyServer."

I tried a few things including `Get-VirtualDisk | Where-Object IsManualAttach -eq $true | Set-VirtualDisk -IsManualAttach $false` and after multiple attempts I was able to set the value to `$false`.

I was able to pull these error messages from Event Viewer:

```
An error occurred during method execution.

Class:      SPACES_VirtualDisk
Method:     Attach
ObjectId:   [REDACTED]
Error Code: 4
```

And

```
An error has occurred during method execution.

Class:      MSFT_VirtualDisk
Method:     Attach
Error Code: 4
Error Message:

Failed
Activity ID: {68137d67-7406-4e9b-b566-050f30b9ea14}
```

Running `Get-VirtualDisk | Connect-VirtualDisk` in PowerShell returns:

```
Connect-VirtualDisk : Failed
Activity ID: {90b49a62-37c6-4dc1-aabc-1489763f0696}
At line:1 char:19
+ Get-VirtualDisk | Connect-VirtualDisk
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...SFT_VirtualDisk) [Connect-VirtualDisk], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 4,Connect-VirtualDisk
```

At this point I am not sure what to do.  I do have some commercial recovery software from RunTime Software but I would rather avoid doing that as that would require my to buy additional drives to offload all my data onto it. I do have a backup of 85% of it online but I would rather not go that route if possible.

Comment: I ended up spending a few days restoring the data and about 20 TB of bandwidth later, I restored everything.  I think what happened is a windows update nuked something permissions wise.  A few updates installed before I powered down the machine before the move and I also had issues powering up my Hyper-V VM that uses a physical disk.  It had a permissions error with accessing it.  I had to remove the drive from the VM settings and then add it back.